# Writing data to an output file

Tags: java, io

I have data in the file `input.txt`. When I run the program, it creates a file called `output.txt` but contains no data. How could I get the data to display in `output.txt`?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DisplayFirstLetter {

    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        try {
            File input = new File("input.txt");
            File output = new File("output.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
            PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = sc.nextLine();
                printer.write(s);
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found. Please scan in new file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No data is often a sign of not *closing* the `Writer`..... Yup. No `close()`. **Always** close your resources, including the `Scanner`.

Comment: close printer and scanner after all operations on them.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas the data is now in the output.txt file, now to figure out how to get the first letter of each line to only show

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the PrinterWriter for the output.txt file to be written.
The recommended way to define a scanner and a printer would be with *try with resources*. The scanner and the printer will be closed automatically in all cases including the case when an exception is thrown.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayFirstLetter {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File input = new File("input.txt");
        File output = new File("output.txt");

        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
             PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output)) {

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = sc.nextLine();
                printer.write(s);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found. Please scan in new file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I do appreciate it

Comment: any idea how to make it so that it will show the first letter on eachline from the input.txt into the output.txt?

Comment: `s.substring(0, 1);` will return a String with only the first letter. You will also need to print a new line character '\n'

Comment: where abouts do i add that in my code? tried after "printer.write(s) but didnt change anything in output.txt

Comment: String s = sc.nextLine().substring(0, 1);
                printer.write(s);
                printer.print('\n');

Comment: AWESOME! that works! now for the stupid stuff, Its correct where its showing CDS but it should show C then the next line D then next line S,

Comment: try `printer.println(s);`

Comment: I apologize, It did work for me! Very busy week trying to get things done. Thank you very much for the help +Rep